# Where can I find Wordpress core functions list and description?

Tags: wordpress

Here are [WP Function Reference](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference) for all users functions.

But I need list of core functions like:
`init, restrict_manage_posts` etc.

Here [WP Action Reference](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference) - list off all core functions, but there are very pure description.

Where can I find it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately AFAIK , there is no ONE place with perfect documentation.
Some of the more known places are :

[The codex .](http://codex.wordpress.org/)

http://adambrown.info/p/wp_hooks/hook/init

http://hitchhackerguide.com/function-filter-action-index/

http://wpseek.com/

http://queryposts.com/

and you can find more on google ..

There is another choice (which might be the best) and that is reading the INLINE comments inside the core file themselves ..